# Do all nonlinear systems of 2 equations in 2 variables have at least one solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I know that not all linear systems of 2 equations in 2 variables have a solution, I was wondering if that is the case also with nonlinear systems.

Comment: What are your thoughts? have you tried playing around with some non-linear systems and seeing what happens? People generally won't answer a question unless they can see the person asking has put in some effort themselves first

Comment: yes, I've been solving some nonlinear systems where the equations represent conics and lines and so far all of them have complex solution/s

Comment: The answer is no.  Here is an example of such a system:  $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=2$.  Two concentric circles that do not intersect.  There are many more examples.

Comment: thank you for the counterexample. The fact is that in other systems I was observing no intersection/s and there were still complex solution/s

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: For example x^2+y^2=3 and y=x-5

Comment: Well, you could come up with even one equation where there are no real solutions yet there are complex solutions.  One example is $x^2+1=0.$  Equations like these motivate the definition of complex numbers.  Nevertheless, we can come up with systems that admit complex solutions to each equation, yet the solution to the system is empty.

Comment: Fine.  Nice example.  If you take the example with concentric circles, even if you allow $x$ and $y$ to be complex, the sum of the squares cannot be both $1$ and $2$.

Comment: via Wikipedia: [Bézout's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_theorem) states that "the number of common pts of two plane [algebraic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve) (that do not already share infinitely-many points) is at most equal to the product of their degrees, and equality holds if one counts pts at infinity and points with complex coordinates, and if each pt is counted with its intersection multiplicity." All circles pass through the same two complex pts on the line at infinity; for two concentric circles, these pts have intersection multiplicity $2$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.  It should be very easy to come up with many examples.  Geometrically, each equation represents a curve in the $xy$-plane.  For there to be a solution to the system of equations, the curves must intersect.

Here is a counter-example:

$$\begin{aligned} x^2+y^2&=1\\ x^2+y^2&=2 \end{aligned}$$

In the $xy$-plane, with $x$ and $y$ both real, these are concentric circles that do not intersect.

Even if you allow $x$ and $y$ to be complex, there are no solutions.  The sum of the squares of two variables cannot simultaneously be both $1$ and $2$.